# Equivalence principle near a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems, singularities, equivalence-principle

At every spacetime point, there is a locally inertial frame in which the effect of gravitation is absent. Can this point be taken near the center of a black hole?

Comment: That is what geodesics are by definition.

Comment: Inside the event horizon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locally inertial coordinates are the [normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates) and these can be defined anywhere in the manifold including inside an event horizon arbitrarily close to the singularity. The singularity is excluded from the manifold so no coordinate system can be defined there.

A simple intuitive choice of normal coordinates are the coordinates of a freely falling observer. These are the [Fermi normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_coordinates). These coordinates can be defined at all points along the trajectory of an observer falling into the black hole up to but not including the singularity.

Answer (score 0):

If the gravitational field is not uniform, at every spacetime point, there is a locally inertial frame in which the effect of gravitation can be regarded as negligible for a given domain.The closer you get to the singularity, the smaller the domain becomes.

Comment: The domain is always a infinitesmall slice of 4D.

Answer (score -4):

No because at the center of a black hole there isnt spacetime at least from the pov of classical General Relativity.

Comment: I welcome openly any criticism.If you think I have written something wrong , feel free to comment on it.I am here to learn just like you.If you dont want to comment then dont downvote at all.Thank you!

Comment: The question did not ask about the point _at_ the centre of a black hole, it asked about a point _near_ the centre of a black hole. Your statement is more or less correct, though it would be better phrased as saying that we define the the manifold so it excludes the singularity, but it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: *If you dont want to comment then dont downvote at all.* I didn’t downvote. However, this site is intentionally designed to have no requirement for downvoters to leave a comment explaining why they downvoted. You need to accept this fact, or you are going to be very unhappy.

Comment: @Ghoster it is not scientific to downvote without explaining why you did it.

Comment: That’s not relevant. People who downvote without explanation are playing by the rules.

Comment: How is it not relevant?The site is called Physics SE and last time I checked Physics is the queen of sciences.

Comment: I’m not looking to debate this. I am simply telling you that instructing people not to downvote without commenting is pointless at best and counter-productive at worst.

Comment: Ok so if a rule is stupid then we should follow it just because it is a rule huh?The answer you gave is what the answer a computer would give any artificial network would give my answer.